# I want to access from url bar "product". ".../product/paracetamol 1" but I give this "Undefined variable: product (0)."

Tags: laravel-5

This is my route

```
Route::resource('/', 'IndexPageController');
Route::get('/shop', 'ShopController@index');
Route::get('/shop/{product}', 'ShopController@show')
```

And this what my method "show":

```
public function show($slug)
{
    $product = Product::where('slug', $slug)->firstOrFail();

    return view('product')->with('product', $product);
}
```

this is in product.blade.php:

```
<h4 class="card-title">{{$product->name}}</h4>
<p class="card-text">{{$product->description}}</p>
```

Comment: Did you check that you get result in your `$product` variable or what value does it have and try to access it in your controller .

Comment: Having the same name of the variable in your route and in your parameter might help better pass on the variable to the controller function. Also your title does not match any of the routes you describe

Comment: Yes, you are right @Mike. I have solved this problem, thank for your comments were helpful.

Comment: @hrt What exactly was the solution ? was it the routes not matching or the naming of the variables ?

Comment: The route name did not coincide with my method. I changed this an it work.